# Проблема в PyCharm Failed building wheel for yarl

Tags: python, aiogram, pip

При загрузке aiogram, используя pip, в консоли PyCharm выскакивает ошибка вконце. При установке дополнительных whl файлов то же самое. В google не нашёл информации на счёт этой проблемы

```
running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting_py.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\yarl
      copying yarl\_url.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\yarl
      copying yarl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\yarl
      running egg_info
      writing yarl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to yarl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to yarl.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to yarl.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.html'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.so'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.pyd'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
      writing manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying yarl\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win32-3.8\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting_c.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyi -> build\lib.win32-3.8\yarl
      copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\yarl
      copying yarl\py.typed -> build\lib.win32-3.8\yarl
      running build_ext
      building 'yarl._quoting_c' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    
      ----------------------------------------
      Failed building wheel for yarl
      Running setup.py clean for yarl
    Failed to build multidict yarl
    Could not build wheels for multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required` нужен компилятор от студии для сборки нативных библиотек

Comment: Комментарий выше помог. Нужно установить Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0.